# MongoDB - search documents through an integer array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to retrieve documents that contain at least one value inside an array. The structure of my document is:

```
{ "_id": 3, 
"username": "111111", 
"name": "XPTO 1", 
"codes": [ 2, 4, 5 ], 
"available": true }


{ "_id": 4, 
"username": "22222", 
"name": "XPTO 2", 
"codes": [ 3, 5 ], 
"available": true }
```

I need to do a find by "codes" and if i search for value "5", i need to retrieve all documents that contains this value inside their array.

I've tried to use #elemMatch but no success...

```
db.user.find({codes: {"$elemMatch": {codes: [2,8]}}}, {"codes":1})
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the `$in` operator for this, `db.user.find({code: {$in: [2,8]}})` But it will not search for where those two values exist in a single document only for documents that have a value 2 or 8 or both

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check for values inside an array just like you compare the values for some field.
So, you would need to do it like this, without using $elemMatch: -

1. If you want to check whether an array contain a single value 5: -

   ```
   db.user.find({codes: 5}, {codes:1})
   ```

   This will return all the document, where `codes` array contain `5`.
2. If you want to check whether an array contain a value out of given set of values: -

   ```
   db.user.find({codes: {$in: [2, 8]}}, {codes:1})
   ```

   This will return documents with array containing either 2 or 8
3. If you want to check whether an array contain all the values in a list: -

   ```
   db.user.find({codes: {$all: [2, 5]}}, {codes:1})
   ```

   This will return all document with array containing both 2 and 5.

Comment: The relevant part of the documentation is [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#comparison) in the "Note" box is says "Fields containing arrays match conditional operators, if only one item matches." That is the crux of the issue, I think.

Comment: @mayhewr.. I'm not really sure whether, that is relevant here. I think, here the concern is about exact match. However, if the range is concerned, then yes that part is important to remember. :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I read it too quickly. That bit merely assumes the point I thought it was trying to make. The documentation seems to assume that you understand that `equals` is equivalent to `contains` in mongo queries, which I don't think is clear to new users at all. The last line of the first note on the linked page should read "This query selects all the documents where the **a** field holds a value of **42** or an array containing **42**." I'll stop rambling now.

Comment: @RohitJain This line almost works:

    `db.user.find({codes: {$in: [2, 8]}}, {codes:1})`

It's retrieves the correct array and _id but i need to retrieve all fields (_id, name, username, codes and available) from my document.

Can i get all fields on result or only array and _id?

Thanks in advance.

David

Comment: @DavidL... Yeah sure. Just remove that 2nd part from there. `{codes:1}` is used to add that you need only `codes` field out. Just fire: - `db.user.find({codes: {$in: [2, 8]}})`, and you are done.

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you very much. I was trying to change `{codes:1}`for `{codes:2}`. Now everything works! :)

Comment: I had this issue: thanks for the help... but seeing the comments and also becoming confused, the `{codes:1}` projection was not a requirement in the first place. It doesn't really add value here and only confuses people (like me and the OP). Maybe remove it?